# "NoneType object is not callable" error when getting web page

Tags: python, download, nonetype

i'm vey new to python and i wrote this code

```
def geturl(url):
    url = urllib.quote(url,'/:')
    log( __name__ ,"Getting url:[%s]" % url)
    try:
        req = urllib2.Request(url)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        content    = response.read()
        return_url = response.geturl()
        response.close()
    except Exception, e:
        log( __name__ ,"Failed to get url because %s" % str(e))
        content    = None
        return_url = None
    return(content, return_url)

def myFunc():
    searchurl="http://www.google.com"
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(3)
    content, response_url = geturl(searchurl)
    if content is None:
        log( __name__ , "Content is None!!")
    content = content.replace("string1", "string2")
```

when i run it, i get this error: NoneType object is not callable.
i can't understand why... i learned that NoneType is the type of None, but i check if "content" variable is None and it's not.
thx for your help

Comment: which line of the code is giving error, can you paste the traceback

Comment: Something else is `none`. Computers are nothing if not logical.

Answer (score 3):

You're not giving the erroneous line, however I suspect the following to be wrong:

```
if content is None:
    log( __name__ , "Content is None!!")
content = content.replace("string1", "string2")
```

When `content` is indeed `None`, a log is emitted but the function keeps executing, until the call to `replace` raises an exception.

Comment: first, thx for your answer. the problem is that content should not be None, and no log line is written to tell that it is. the line that gives the error is the one with content.replace, as you already figured out